# Two point charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential-energy

Is it possible to have an arrangement of two point charges separated by a finite distance such that the electrical potential energy of the arrangement is the same as if the two charges were infinitely far apart. Why? Or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Let's put this in a coordinate system.

If the two point charges are infinitely far apart from the origin for example (which implies they are infinitely far apart from each other), the electric potential is always zero at any finite distance from the origin.

For two point equal and opposite charges, the electric potential is zero at any point equidistant from the two charges.

But no, the electric potential energy of the system of those charges cannot be zero.